# Count how many times a specific json/word appears

Tags: json, node.js

If I have a website that contains JSON with multiple `"usrId":`, how can I count how many times this exists? I do not know if it's better to count JSON objects or just count how many times that word exists on the webpage, also I wouldn't know how to get started, how can I do this?

```
request(getusr, function(err, res, body) {
  let json = JSON.parse(body);
  let usramount = // count how many times usrId appears
})
```

Example json:

```
  {  
     "id":"example",
     "usrId":"example"
  },
  {  
     "id":"example"
     "usrId":"example",
  },
```

Comment: Can you share an example of what you mean 'contains JSON with multiple "usrId":'?

Comment: @MARyan87I have edited the code, this is a small bit but basically I want to count how many times usrId appears on the whole page, in this case, 2

Answer (score 2):

```
(body.match(/"usrId":/g) || []).length;
```

should do the trick.